# Why can't I find ubuntu-restricted-extras in the menu?

Tags: package-management, launcher

So I installed the restricted extras but I can't open them nor find them anywhere. I've typed it in the search bar..still nothing. It says its installed but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 12):

The `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package doesn't install any applications *at all*.

What the package *does* do is install [media codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Codec) which can be used to play patent or copyright encumbered media formats. These cannot be included in the default Ubuntu installation because of patent and copyright restrictions.
Codecs provided by this package include `MP3`, `MPEG`, `Quicktime`, `Windows Media Format`, and many others.

If you're looking for more information, please refer to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) in the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: It also installs the flash installer, Microsoft core fonts and a RAR archive decompression tool.

Answer (score 1):

The restricted extras are not regular programs that would appear in the menu. They are files that get called by programs. What in particular are you looking for?